# How to run multiple Python scripts in a Docker image or container that depends on another image?

Tags: python, docker, scrapy, scrapy-splash

I have a few .py files that I want to run in a Docker image.

But they need the scrapy-splash Docker image to function well. How will I be able to run those .py files in a Docker container or image while also running scrapy-splash? I am planning to run it on a VPS server.

Answer (score 0):

You have two choices:

1. Run the python scripts in the entrypoint, after splash. To run splash in background and then execute your scripts you'll need an entrypoint like this:

`ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/bash", "-c", "python3 splash <SPLASH OPTIONS> & python3 your_script.py && python3 your_second_script.py"]`

This way the container will end after running the scripts.

2. Run the splash container in detached mode and then execute the scripts with `docker exec`.